# how to show an activity only during holding touch

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, ontouchlistener

On my first activity i have an OnTouchListener set on a ListView, and I am detecting touches with the onTouch() method. When i get a MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, i launch a second activity. I would like to detect the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP on this second activity, so the second activity can finish() itself when the touch-up occurs.

For now, the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is well detected on the first activity in the listener. But the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is also detected in the first activity (even if the second activity is displayed while i stop holding the touch)

My aim is to close the second activity on touch-up. So the second activity is supposed to be displayed only as long as the user hold his touch.

So i think i need :
1) either a way to finish the second activity from the first one, since the touch-up is detected on the first one. But when i startActivity() from the first activity to create the second one, i do not have any reference to the newly created activity, so i cannot finish() it from the first activity.
For this i would need a reference to the second activity in the first one. But when i startActivity() i do not have such information.

2) either a way for the second activity to detect a touch-up even if the touch-down was done on another activity. But even if i implemented an OnTouchListener of the all-encompassing relativeLayout, no touch-up was detected. It was still detected on the first activity, even if i touch-up while second activity is displayed. But after that touch-up, if i touch-up&down, these events are well handled in the second activity. So the listener of the second activity is working well, but for some reason it cannot get the touch-up of a touch initiated on the first activity. I also made the onTouch() returning false on the first activity, to let the event free to go to the listener i created on the second activity ; it did not work. Still have the touch-up handled by the first activity.

For the record, the first activity is actually a fragment but i guess it does not matter...

Thanks for your help

Comment: TL;DR you cannot display an `Activity` only on press but you could display a `Dialog` or a `Window`.

Comment: You can't do this with activities. There is no way for another activity to suddenly take over a touch event stream like this. You will have to implement everything in one activity and manage the UI with views or Fragments in that single activity.

Comment: Thank you both for you comments.I will use a View.